# CodeIgniter: Ajax Update and Delete Not Working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, crud

I'm having trouble working with my CRUD right as I am new with CodeIgniter and ajax. The ajax call performs a success but it does not validate any changes that should happen to the database (updating data to the database). This is an ajax call through a modal, btw. In the network, when I click the js file, it just preview "true".

here are shortened source code

Manager_Model.php

```
public function managerList()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('m_ID', 'DESC');
        $managerlist = $this->db->get('managers');
        return $managerlist->result();
    }
    public function managerAdd()
    {
        $data = array(
            'm_fname'       => $this->input->post('fullname'),
            'm_email'       => $this->input->post('email'),
            'm_contact'     => $this->input->post('contact'),
            'm_type'        => $this->input->post('level'),
            'm_dept'        => $this->input->post('department'),
            'm_username'    => $this->input->post('username'),
            'm_password'    => $this->input->post('password'),
            'm_status'      => $this->input->post('status'),
            'm_datecreated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        $this->db->set('m_sessID', 'UUID()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('managers', $data);
    }
    public function managerUpdate()
    {
        $emid      = $this->input->post('emid');
        $epassword = $this->input->post('epassword');
        $efname    = $this->input->post('efullname');
        $estatus   = $this->input->post('estatus');

        $this->db->set('m_fname', $efname);
        $this->db->set('m_password', $epassword);
        $this->db->set('m_status', $estatus);
        $this->db->where('m_ID', $emid);
        $result = $this->db->update('managers');
        return $result;
    }
    public function managerDelete()
    {   
        $dmid = $this->input->post('dmid');
        $this->db->where('m_ID', $dmid);
        $result = $this->db->delete('managers');
        return $result;
    }
```

Admin.php (my controller)

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('Manager_Model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('adminsales/admin');
    }

    public function managers()
    {
        $data = $this->Manager_Model->managerList();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function makeManager()
    {
        $data = $this->Manager_Model->managerAdd();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    public function updateManager()
    {
        $data = $this->Manager_Model->managerUpdate();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    public function deleteManager() 
    {
        $data = $this->Manager_Model->managerDelete();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

my ajax file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
show_manager(); //call function show all product
$('#mydata').dataTable();
//function show all manager
function show_manager(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'admin/managers',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html += '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_ID+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_username+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_fname+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_status+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_lastlogintime+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_lastloginIP+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].m_loginsystem+'</td>'+
                        '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm manager_edit" data-m_ID="'+data[i].m_ID+'" data-m_username="'+data[i].m_username+'" data-m_email="'+data[i].m_email+'" data-m_fname="'+data[i].m_fname+'" data-m_status="'+data[i].m_status+'">Edit'+data[i].m_ID+'</a>'+' '+
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm manager_delete" data-m_ID="'+data[i].m_ID+'">Delete</a>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
            }
            $('#show_data').html(html);
        }
    });
}

//posting data to database
$('#btn_save').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var fullname   = $('#fullname').val();
    var email      = $('#email').val();
    var contact    = $('#contact').val();
    var department = $('#department').val();
    var level      = $('#level').val();
    var status     = $('#status').val();
    var username   = $('#username').val();
    var password   = $('#password').val();
    var cpassword  = $('#cpassword').val();

    if (fullname == "" || email == "" || contact == "" || department == ""
    || level == "" || status == "" || username == "" || password == "") {
        alert("Please input required fields!");
    }
    else if (password != cpassword) {
        alert('Password did not matched!');
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "admin/makeManager",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : {fullname:fullname, email:email, contact:contact, department:department, 
                level:level, status:status, username:username, password:password},
            success: function(data){
                $('[name="fullname"]').val("");
                $('[name="email"]').val("");
                $('[name="contact"]').val("");
                $('[name="department"]').val("");
                $('[name="level"]').val("");
                $('[name="stats"]').val("");
                $('[name="username"]').val("");
                $('[name="password"]').val("");
                alert('Data Added Successfully');
                $('#insert_manager_form')[0].reset();
                show_manager();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});

//get data for update record
$('#show_data').on('click','.manager_edit',function(){
    var estatus   = $(this).data('m_status');
    var epassword = $(this).data('m_password');
    var efullname = $(this).data('m_fname');
    var eemail    = $(this).data('m_email');
    var eusername = $(this).data('m_username');

    $('#Modal_Edit').modal('show');
    $('[name="eusername"]').val(eusername);
    $('[name="estatus"]').val(estatus);
    $('[name="efullname"]').val(efullname);
    $('[name="epassword"]').val(epassword);
    $('[name="eemail"]').val(eemail);
});

//update record to database
 $('#btn_update').on('click',function(){
    var estatus   = $('#estatus').val();
    var epassword = $('#epassword').val();
    var efullname = $('#efullname').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "admin/updateManager",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data : {estatus:estatus, epassword:epassword, efullname:efullname},
        success: function(data){
            $('[name="estatus"]').val("");
            $('[name="epassword"]').val("");
            $('[name="efullname"]').val("");
            alert('Data Updated Successfully');
            show_manager();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

//get data for delete record
$('#show_data').on('click','.manager_delete',function(){
    var dmid = $(this).data('m_ID');

    $('#Modal_Delete').modal('show');
    $('[name="dmid"]').val(dmid);
});

//delete record to database
 $('#btn_delete').on('click',function(){
    var dmid = $('#dmid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "admin/deleteManager",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data : {dmid:dmid},
        success: function(data){
            $('[name="dmid"]').val("");
            $('#Modal_Delete').modal('hide');
            alert("Data has been deleted. It cannot be changed!");
            show_product();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

EDIT MODAL

```
<form>
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Product</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="hidden" name="emid" id="emid" class="form-control" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="eusername" id="eusername" class="form-control" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="eemail" id="eemail" class="form-control" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="efullname" id="efullname" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Status</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="estatus" id="estatus" value="ON">ON</label>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="estatus" id="estatus" value="CLOSE">CLOSE</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="password" name="epassword" id="epassword" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="password" name="ecpassword" id="ecpassword" class="form-control">


         </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

DELETE MODAL

```
<form>
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Product</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                       <strong>Are you sure to delete this record?</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dmid" id="dmid" class="form-control">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

PS: add and viewing works perfectly fine. I don't know where I am wrong. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: already tried ways on how to solve my problem but I just don't get it right

Comment: on your model, `managerUpdate()` expecting `emid` to be posted, but you haven't send it on your ajax request, why is that?

Comment: as I've said, I'm new to ajax so not quite sure why. If I click my edit button a modal pops up and it already contains the specific data of that specific row that I clicked. So I assumed that I don't really need to send it in ajax since I'm already fetching it(?) Am I wrong though?

Comment: I might be wrong in shortening my ajax so I'm editing it. check the upper part so u could understand

Comment: I guess it's the reason the update fails. Could you show the html modal where the `emid` is at?

Comment: check new edit I put all there is to it that might be causing the problem. thanks

Comment: did that `emid` input automatically populated with data once the modal is popped up? or is it still has empty value when the modal is popped up?

Comment: it's already populated. like what you normally see in an 
edit button->modal pops up->input tags(e.g <input name="efullname" id="efullname">) already populated within the exact row I clicked button. 

that's why I've been wondering why Ive been coding it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please recieve ID in the controller and send it to the model.

Change the your code with below one.

**In controller**

```
 public function updateManager()
  {
    $emid = $this->input->post('emid');
    $data = $this->Manager_Model->managerUpdate($emid);
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
 public function deleteManager() 
  {

    $data = $this->Manager_Model->managerDelete();
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

**In Model**

```
public function managerUpdate($emid = '')
  {
    $epassword = $this->input->post('epassword');
    $efname    = $this->input->post('efullname');
    $estatus   = $this->input->post('estatus');

    $this->db->set('m_fname', $efname);
    $this->db->set('m_password', $epassword);
    $this->db->set('m_status', $estatus);
    $this->db->where('m_ID', $emid);
    $result = $this->db->update('managers');
    return $result;
  }
public function managerDelete($dmid = '')
  {   
    $this->db->where('m_ID', $dmid);
    $result = $this->db->delete('managers');
    return $result;
  }
```

Also, try after putting `input` before your name selector.

Change

```
$('[name="fullname"]').val("");
```

with below one

```
$('input[name="fullname"]').val("");
```

Comment: See the console or network after submit. You should see the parameters which send to the server end. Which fields are submitting? Is it contains the required id `emid` or `dmid` ?

Comment: in the console, while adding data displays a violation in 'click' handler, the edit shows violation in 'load' handler...in network, it just displays a text "true" in the preview tab and nothing else

Comment: Click on `header` tab. It will show the parameters with the value which is sent by the client end. I'm temporarily adding an image to the answer please refer to it.

Comment: I see now, it's sending 'emid' without any value. However, the inputs which I (possibly) edited returns with what I typed in it after clicking submit.

Comment: You can check whether `emid` or `dmid` is sending or not. And what is the value of it? If the values are blank then the issue is that the value does not set in the hidden input.

Comment: Ok, it means when you click on the edit button, you are unable to put value in the `emid` field. May same issue for delete case. please check it.

Comment: @AldenSisonHernandez well done, You got the issue. please fix it and check again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also send the `emid` for the `updateManager()` controller :

```
//update record to database
 $('#btn_update').on('click',function(){
    var estatus   = $('#estatus').val();
    var epassword = $('#epassword').val();
    var efullname = $('#efullname').val();
    var emid      = $('#emid').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "admin/updateManager",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data : {estatus:estatus, epassword:epassword, efullname:efullname, emid:emid},
        success: function(data){
            $('[name="estatus"]').val("");
            $('[name="epassword"]').val("");
            $('[name="efullname"]').val("");
            alert('Data Updated Successfully');
            show_manager();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. Too bad. I'm getting headache about this already. I also tried transferring input->('emid') from controller to model. but didn't worked